# PostgreSQL output timestamp with time zone

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timestamp

Trying to output a `timestamp with time zone` in the PostgreSQL.
I have tried several params, the first two are fine.

(1):

```
select time at time zone 'UTC' from sf where id='365498691097858048';
```

it outputs:

```
2013-08-08 15:44:13
```

(2):

```
select time at time zone 'PDT' from sf where id='365498691097858048';
```

it outputs

```
2013-08-08 08:44:13
```

But the third one confuses me:

(3):

```
select time at time zone 'UTC-07' from sf where id='365498691097858048';
```

```
2013-08-08 22:44:13
```

'UTC-07' is the same as 'PDT', why the outputs are totally different?

Comment: And `time` is supposed to be the name for a column holding .. what? a `timestamp` or a `timestamp with time zone`? I can't find your table definition. Either way, don't use the reserved word `time` as column name - even less for a column of different data type.

Comment: Maybe PostgreSQL is seeing `UTC-07`, parsing as far as `UTC` and going "I know that time zone", ignoring the `-07` suffix. I can't reproduce it here on my 9.3 install if so - what PostgreSQL version are you running? (**Always** include your PostgreSQL version in questions).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter , Hello, it is timestamp with time zone.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because PostgreSQL is being compliant with the POSIX standard when you use timezones without names.

From the [IANA Timezone database](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/d62830d089244db5f75ae43ecf08aecd1f0e50da/etcetera#L36-L42):

> ```
> # Be consistent with POSIX TZ settings in the Zone names,
> # even though this is the opposite of what many people expect.
> # POSIX has positive signs west of Greenwich, but many people expect
> # positive signs east of Greenwich.  For example, TZ='Etc/GMT+4' uses
> # the abbreviation "-04" and corresponds to 4 hours behind UT
> # (i.e. west of Greenwich) even though many people would expect it to
> # mean 4 hours ahead of UT (i.e. east of Greenwich).
> ```

From the POSIX Spec [as documented for GNU `libc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html) (emphasis mine):

> The offset specifies ***the time value you must add to the local time to get a Coordinated Universal Time value.*** It has syntax like [+|-]hh[:mm[:ss]]. This is positive if the local time zone is west of the Prime Meridian and negative if it is east. The hour must be between 0 and 24, and the minute and seconds between 0 and 59.